# Determine if page is not ready yet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loading

I want to know if I can determine if the page is not ready yet or not? because if the page is not ready I would like to insert an animation there.

I found something like this from previous Questions like this:

```
var ready = false;
$(document).ready(function () {
    ready = true;
});
```

but it doesn't really help me. is there any other way to determine if page is not ready yet? or any way to add loading screen when page is not ready.

Comment: Why it doesn't help you?

Comment: Why can't you display the "loading screen" and hide it with this $(document).ready function when the page is ready ?

Comment: @OlivierG you got a point there.

Answer (score 10):

I would create the base page with the loading animation as part of it.  Then you detect when the page *is* ready and remove it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#loading").hide();
});
```